# asp.net razor page SSO Azure AD

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-active-directory, single-sign-on

I'm working with .NET 6.0 and trying to implement SSO using the microsoft login service. I don't want to manage users myself (registration and storing).

I have created an application in the azure portal and set the redirect URI to `https://localhost:7013/signin-oidc` and logout URL to `https://localhost:7013/signout-oidc`

I've added the following to my appsettings.json:

```
  "AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com",
    "TenantId": "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "ClientId": "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc",
    "SignedOutCallbackPath": "/signout-oidc"
  }
```

Ive added the following to my program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

builder.Services.Configure<OpenIdConnectOptions>(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    options => options.SignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

builder.Services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
}).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

Then I added a scaffolded identity item and selected Login, Logout, and ExternalLogin.
When I launch the application and press the `OpenIdConnect` button I am correctly prompted to login using my company microsoft account. However I am returned to a page where I have to register using an email.

Although I'm returned to a page for registration I still experience an `InvalidOperationException` on `ExternalLoginSignInAsync` complaining about `Cannot create a DbSet for 'IdentityUserLogin<string>' because this type is not included in the model for the context.`

Is it easily possible to strip all parts requiring me to register and store user information and instead fully rely on the authentication from microsoft/azure?

Comment: I think your SignInScheme is incorrect. Auth options should be DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AutheticationScheme. OIDC SignInScheme should be "Cookies" unless you're using an extenal login such as facebook.

Answer (score 0):

I got the below error when I tried with your code

> ```cs
>  InvalidOperationException: No authenticationScheme was specified, and there was no DefaultChallengeScheme found. 
>  The default schemes can be set using either AddAuthentication(string defaultScheme) or AddAuthentication(Action<AuthenticationOptions>
> configureOptions).
> ```

Thanks @GH DevOps for the comment.

Yes, as mentioned by GH DevOps the way you set the `AuthenticationScheme` is incorrect.

The error clearly says to set the `AuthenticationScheme`.

Check the below code which worked for me.

Add the `AuthenticationScheme` and `SignInScheme`  in the same options.

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme; 
    options.DefaultSignInScheme = IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})

.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
builder.Services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticatedUser().Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
}).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();


var app = builder.Build();
---
---
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
```

- Update `Microsoft.Identity.Web` and `Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI` to the latest version.

***Output:***
[image]

[image]

- Make sure not to include the unnecessary code related to Identity in the middleware.
- AFAIK,yes you can rely on the Microsoft authentication.

Refer [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-8.0) for more details.